# use a page with framesets as a modal page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a simple Statistics.aspx page with a frameset, and I want to use it as a modal page in a web user control. I have a javascript function and I use it in a gridview Item template as below ::

```
<script>
function ViewStatistics(AdId)
 {
     modalDialog('../../../CMSWebParts/Advertise/Tools/View_Statistics.aspx', 'ViewStatistics', 700, 600);
  }
```

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnStatistics" runat="server" CommandName="statistics" 
     ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/Images/Objects/__REPORTING__/object.png" 
     ToolTip="View Statistics" Width="18px" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'        
     alt="ViewStatistics" OnClientClick=" ViewStatistics (10 ); return false;" />
```

my statistics.aspx page code is as below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="plcContent" runat="Server">
<%--    <div>
<iframe src="User_ADs_Analytics_Statistics.aspx" >hi</iframe>
<iframe src="User_ADs_Analytics_Statistics.aspx" >hi2</iframe>
 </div>--%>
<frameset border="0" cols="220,*" id="colsFramesetAnalytics" runat="server">
    <frame name="analtree" src="User_ADs_Analytics_Statistics.aspx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" />
    <frameset border="0" rows="111, 154, *" runat="server" id="rowsFrameset">
        <frame name="analmonths" src="../../../mjtest.aspx" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" />
        <!--  <frame name="analdays" src="User_ADs_Analytics_Statistics.aspx" frameborder="0" />
        <frame name="analreport" src="../../../CMSDesk/blank.htm" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" /> -->
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        <p id="p1">
            This HTML frameset displays multiple Web pages. To view this frameset, use a Web
            browser that supports HTML 4.0 and later.
        </p>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

when I use iframe it works nice but when I use frameset it shows nothing.

Comment: "Nothing" as in "not even the noframes message"?